# Find next and previous link in a hierarchy

Tags: jquery, find, anchor

I have a hierarchy with links nested in list element like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Page 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1.2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 1.2.1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 1.2.2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1.3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 2</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Page 2.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 2.2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 3</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Page 3.1</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 3.1.1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 3.1.2</a></li>
                </ul>
            <li><a href="#">Page 3.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 3.3</a></li>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 3.1.1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 3.1.2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Basically just a sitemap. But I want to make next and previous links with jQuery, which finds the active page you're on (probably by checking for a class), and finding the previous and next anchor element (taking no regards of the hierarchy). I've tried with `next()`, `previous()` and `find()` but can't seem to get it to work.

What is the easiest way to get the anchor elements before and after the current one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var selected = $("a.selected");
var anchors = $("a");

var pos = anchors.index(selected);
var next = anchors.get(pos+1);
var prev = anchors.get(pos-1);
```

Comment: i think second line should be..var anchors = $('a');

Comment: Wow, it's that simple. Surprisingly little code as well. Thanks!

Comment: What would the HTML markup look like to implement the 'Next' and 'Previous' buttons/links?

Answer (score 7):

Assuming the `<a>` for the current page has `class="current"`, then you can do this to find the flattened index of the current page within the sitemap:

```
// Get current anchor
var currentA = $("a.current");

// Get array of all anchors in sitemap
var anchors = $("ul a"); // (would be better if you gave the ul an id)

// Find the index of the current anchor, within the (flattened) sitemap
var i = anchors.index(currentA);
```

I split the above into 3 lines for illustrative purposes, but you can shorten the above code to:

```
var i = $("ul a").index($("a.current"));
```

Then you can write functions to navigate the page to the next and prev links:

```
// Go to the next link
function goToNext() {
    if (i + 1 < anchors.length) {
        window.location.href = anchors[i + 1].href;
    }
}

// Go to the previous link
function goToPrev() {
    if (i > 0) {
        window.location.href = anchors[i - 1].href;
    }
}
```

Finally, attach these functions to your next and prev anchors:

```
$("a.next").click(goToNext);
$("a.prev").click(goToPrev);
```